# keep getting undefined request with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

using ajax code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: "last-id-test.php",
    type: "POST",
});

$.ajax({
    data: {theinfo: 'forminfo'},      
    success: function(data) {alert(data)},
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert('Error submitting request.')}   
});
```

and then simple php of last-id-test.php:

```
$showme = $_GET['theinfo'];
```

I always get the error 'undefined index - theinfo'...

I cant see my mistake?

Comment: You're using POST in the jQuery code while using GET in PHP ...

Comment: Well first off you're using `POST`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments GET and POST methods result in data being passed in to different global variables in PHP -- GET == $_GET  POST == $_POST

So in this case try in your php:

`$showme = $_POST['theinfo'];`

Useful for debugging is

`print_r($_GET); // or $_POST or $_COOKIE`

More info on these global variables: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    url: "last-id-test.php",
    type: "POST",
});

$.ajax({
    data: {'theinfo': 'forminfo'},      
    success: function(data) {alert(data)},
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){alert('Error submitting request.')}   
});
```

**Note that the single quotes are used around the variable name.**

Now you need to access the passing variable using POST array since your type is set as `POST`

```
$showme = $_POST['theinfo'];
```

Comment: You think `{theinfo: 'forminfo'}` wouldn't have worked? No, it was perfectly fine

Comment: Its better to enclose variables with quotes because of different browsers compatibility. Sometimes browsers aren't happy with this flexibility.

Comment: There is no browser in the world that does not understand `{theinfo: 'forminfo'}`.

Comment: Agreed. But I do it this way and so it was reflected in my code i suggested.. Is there something wrong with enclosing a variable in quotes?